# Change a color of odd array elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Lets say I have a string of 5 letters in COLOR and want C L and R to be of color blue or whatever color just different from even letters O and O. I tried to convert it to an array and then use for loop. But dont know how to assign color value to array element. This is code I have so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!-- Hide JavaScript

var mystring='color';

var myArray = mystring.split('');

for(i=0; i < myArray.length; i++){

//checking for odd positions
if(i % 2 == 0){
mojArray[i]//how to add color code to each element?
}
else{
mojArray[i];
}
document.write(myArray[i]);
}
-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Array values/strings can't have color values. Elements that can have color properties are HTML elements. Not sure what mojArray is, but if it contains HTML/DOM elements, you can do something like `mojArray[i].style.color = '#ff0000';` (that's hex code for red, though and valid CSS color notation would work).

You're doing a good job recognizing the even/odd elements, you just need to figure out (and explain better in the question) what are you trying to paint.

That should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following:

```
function colorOdd (el, color) {
    // split the string, removing any leading white-space:
    var str = el.firstChild.nodeValue.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'').split('');

    // iterate over the split characters in the string:
    for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++){
        // if the iterator is an odd number, wrap the string in a span (and style)
        str[i] = i%2 === 0 ? '<span style="color: ' + color + ';">' + str[i] + '</span>' : str[i];
    }
    /* join the string back together (with empty-space) and set the innerHTML
       of the element upon which the function was called:
    */
    el.innerHTML = str.join('');
}

colorOdd(document.getElementById('demo'),'#f90');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/SkP3w/1/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var mystring='color';
for(var i=0;i<mystring.length;i++)
{
  var ch = mystring.charAt(i);
  if(i%2==0)
  {
     ducument.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += "<span style='color:red'>"+ch+"</span>"
  }
  else
  {
     ducument.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += "<span style='color:blue'>"+ch+"</span>"
  }
}


<div id="mydiv"> </div>
```